# Crystal Reports against OLAP / XMLA / SimbaO2X-server

Tags: crystal-reports, connection, database-connection, olap, xmla

I'm trying to convert some old Excel-reports to Crystal Reports. The excel sheets uses OLAP-cubes and connects to a database using a XMLA connection over a SimbaO2X driver.
I just can't figure out which connection settings to use in Crystal Reports to be able to connect to the database.
I've tried both XML and OLAP connections, but just can't get a database connection.

Any help with the connection setting would be appreciated!

**Edit:** The database is a bit of a black box; it's *probably* an Oracle database (it was an Oracle database before the end user frontend was rewritten in java. They could have changed the database as well.) I have however no success with neither the Oracle Server nor the Microsoft OLE DB for Oracle connection method.

I have also this morning found a SimbaO2X provider under the OLE DB folder. While not working it's the best so far -- it accepts the username and password and lets me select which database to connect to but then fails with ADO Error Code: 0x80040e73 (Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.) At least I have something to go on.

I'm running Crystal Reports XI if someone needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

- Upgrade Crystal Reports XI to Release 2, service pack 4.
- Update from service pack 4 to service pack 6.

Upgrades and updates can be downloaded from the [SAP Community Network](http://service.sap.com/sap/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm)

A connection can now be made with the SimbaO2X OLE DB driver. This solution should also resolve connection problems with some other databases as well.

However, adding a table to the report results in a 0x800a0cc1 error (Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal)